# Reloading a route of the same site in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, backbone.js

A section of code was developed for us, and the basic (and simplified) design is as follows:

The landing page has two sections, with an example of section 1 as below

[image: Section 1]

Which is fairly straightforward: click on link 1-1 to 1-N and it will route you to the page, e.g. http://testpage.com/link1-1

Now in section 2 things work similar as seen below:

[image: Section 2]

With the difference that any link on section 2 that routes to a page has information (not important for this question) and an iFrame.  This iFrame, depending on which link is clicked, loads the links from section 1.

My first problem here is with the use of the iFrame.  A lot of things happen here: it reloads the entire site (that means bootstrapping everything from scratch).  Some of the information is kind of hard-wired not to reload with an if-statement that checks if the site is now loading in an iFrame.  It all feels a bit dirty to me.  Some of the commands cross-communicate from the iFrame to the parent window and some not.  It is impossible to track everything.

There is no intermediate point for the iFrame.  The main app's routing checks if it is in the iFrame and from there **randomly** routes to one of the links 1-N of section 1.  This means the iFrame always loads a lot of data, even if the user doesn't select it.

I've mentioned the following problems to them:

- it's unmanageable
- it's memory inefficient
- it impacts on loading time

Reasons they say they've done this:

- Sandboxing: No need to redo CSS
- Code reuse
- No need to keep track of which scripts and assets, memory is cleaned easily with the iFrame

I disagree quite strongly with the first two statements, because the iFrame loads a new version of the CSS and the code can be reused, without using an iFrame.  I am a bit in the dark with the 3'rd.

Now to my question.  Is this the only way to do it?  The system runs on Backbone.js and I am almost entirely convinced that this can be done it a cleaner an more efficient way.  How difficult is it to clear all resources that will be loaded if the link is injected into a div, instead of an iFrame?

Comment: *"Clients developed code for us"* - what..? Are you the guy writing code, or the guy paying for code..? My understanding of *client* is the later... Since when clients started writing code..!

Comment: @TJ edited the question. Not sure how that relates to the question anyway?

Comment: Nah I was just wondering..!

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the main reasons we have mv* frameworks is code re usability.

We have view components so that we can easily instantiate and inject it anywhere you want. Loading the entire application in an `<iframe>` at a specific route to display a particular view doesn't make sense and loses the point of having *single page* application. One of their major advantage is that browsers don't have to create entirely new documents and load (and process - compiling scripts, computing css styles for drawing etc) the same resources over and over.

- "Sandboxing: No need to redo CSS"

Might be valid depending on the way CSS is written. For example when loaded freely in `testpage.com:link`, The view might be directly under a div with `container` class, but when loaded in the small box in section two, it might be nested deep inside it (*or worst case, it might not even be there*).

So a CSS selector like `.container > .linkView` won't work in the second case, and it needs to be modified into `.container  .linkView`

The CSS changes that might be required totally depend on the DOM structure, complexity and the way it is written currently.

- Code reuse

This point of theirs is actually against them because the view component they have created can not be *re-* used anywhere else in the application, which is why they had to load it in an `<iframe>` as an entirely different application instance

Loading the entire application in an `<iframe>` is not code reuse, that's creating another instance of application, nothing is being *reused* there. Reusing  the same view in different places of the application with minimal CSS changes (*if required*) is actual code reuse.

- No need to keep track of which scripts and assets, memory is cleaned easily with the iFrame

tracking scripts and assets..? Why do we need to keep track of script and assets? It is not like we manually *unload* scripts and assets from code in general. Doesn't browsers this handle these stuff?

If the user happened to visit `link 1-1` in section 1, when we visits the same in section 2, In a single page app we have the advantage that the required assets are already loaded (*and processed*) in browser, and if it wasn't let the browser load the *extra* assets required. It is far better than the browser loading and compiling everything from underscore and jquery for the `<iframe>` document in my opinion.

Regarding memory management - removing the view while navigating to different routes should free up the memory unless there's a problem with the code. - in other words there is a memory leak in code. The right action to take in that case is to fix the leak.

---

Regarding your first point:

- it's unmanageable

This depends on who is managing the code, if it is those who came up with the `<iframe>`, maybe it's easier for them to manage :D

I completly agree with the other 2 points.